# The Black formatter - how to scan only chosen directories

Tags: python, jenkins-pipeline

I want to implement black scanner in jenkins shared libraries. The idea is that when library see a `pyproject.toml` it will perform the black check. The command is set to `black --check ./` . This will be set once for all projects so should be as universal as possible (check is set for all files).

How to set `pyproject.toml` so it can scan only chosen directories?

I tried to exclude everything and include only one i want. But this does not work. My regex-fu is very weak.

```
[tool.black]
exclude = '''
/(
  | *
)/

'''
include = '''
/(
  | pytest/**
)/

'''
```

Answer (score 8):

I found answer by myself. Just ...

```
[tool.black]
include = 'pytest\/.*\.pyi?$'
```

... or for multiple directories ...

```
[tool.black]
include = 'pytest\/.*\.pyi?$|tests\/subdirectory\/.*\.pyi?$'
```